# Magento 2 error: CGI Generic Local File Inclusion

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, frontend, backend

I get an error **"CGI Generic Local File Inclusion"** in the report. The issue is on the Magento or server side, and how can I solve it? Any suggestions or help to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance!